# ng-repeat alternative in plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically create bootstrap wells which contains particular information about some raised ticket like ticket no, status of ticket, etc. All these details should populate dynamically from the response.
I can only use JavaScript. How to implement the same in plain JavaScript?

I have successfully created bootstrap wells but how to populate data against each field dynamically using JavaScript?

```html
<body>       
  <div id="table"></div>

  <script>
    var ticketDetails = [
      {status:"pending", App_name:"demo1", req_id:1234, Appr: "no", tct_no: "AB1234"},
      {status:"approved", App_name:"demo2", req_id:654, Appr: "yes", tct_no: "AB8769"},
      {status:"dispatched", App_name:"demo3", req_id:34, Appr: "yes", tct_no: "AB1241"}
    ];

    var a = '<div class="container">';
        a += '<div class="well" style="color:#fff; background-color:pink;"><div class="row">';
        a += '<div class="col-xs-6">REQUEST#</div>';
        a += '<div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;">STATUS</div>';
        a += '</div>';
        a += '<div>';
        a += '<div class="row">';
        a += '<div class="col-xs-4">Approval</div>';
        a += '<div class="col-xs-4">Approver Name</div>';
        a += '<div class="col-xs-4">Ticket Number</div>';
        a += '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += a;
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all. I highly recommend to you to use map for that and not for loop:

```
const html = ticketDetails.map( item =>{
 return `<div class="container">
   <div class="well" style="color:#fff; background-color:pink;">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">REQUEST#</div>
       <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;">STATUS</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">${item['status']}</div>
       <div class="col-xs-4">${item['App_name']}</div>
       <div class="col-xs-4">${item['tct_no']}</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>` ; 
});

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = html.join('');
```

[].map create a new array, array of strings in that case.And [].Join('') join the array back to a single string.